# How to model this relationship efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have an **Exercise** table, each Exercise can be 1 of 5 **Exercise Type** (eg. cardio, timed activity, weights, combination of weights and timed, something else). Each of the different types stores the data in a different manner (eg. cardio is intensity and time, timed is just time in minutes, weights is sets x reps x weight, and something else could be something else).

So its a given that I have an Exercise table, but not sure how to model the Exercise Type and store the associated exercise data for each exercise type. Each Exercise will be of only one Exercise Type and each Exercise Type can belong to many Exercises.

I was leaning towards just an Exercise table and an Exercise Type table and have a many to one relationship, but I can't figure out how best to store each exercises data.

This is going to be modeled for Entity Framework 6 and MS SQL Server.

Comment: It sounds like your question is really about how to model Exercise Type. You've got the 1:N solution already.

Answer (score 1):

I think your scenario is good for Inheritance (using Table-per-Hierarchy), here is my suggested design:

```
public Exercise 
{    
    public int ExerciseId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ExerciseBaseTypeId")]
    public ExerciseBaseType ExerciseType {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public int ExerciseBaseTypeId {get;set;}

}

public ExerciseBaseType 
{
    public int BaseTypeId{get;set;}

    public Link<Exercise> Exercises {get;set;}

    //put other base properties that is common to all exercise types        
}

public Cardio : ExerciseBaseType {
    public string Intensity {get;set;}
    public int Time {get;set;}
}

public Timed : ExerciseBaseType {
    public int Duration {get;set;}
}

public Weight : ExerciseBaseType {
    public int Sets {get;set;}
    public int Weight {get;set;}
}
```

Here is your dbcontext file:

```
public class ExerciseDbContext : DbContext
{

    public ExerciseDbContext()
        : base("ExerciseDatabase"){ }
}

public DbSet<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }

public DbSet<ExerciseBaseType> ExerciseTypes { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Exercise>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.ExerciseBaseType)
            .WithMany(ebt => ebt.Exercises)
            .HasForeignKey(e.ExerciseBaseTypeId);
}
```

As an example, lets add a Timed Exercise and attach it to the exercise with id #1:

```
ExerciseDbContext db = new ExerciseDbContext();

var timedExercise = new Timed();
timedExercise.Duration = 60;
//set the other base properties

db.Exercises
  .Single(e => e.ExerciseId = 1)
  .ExerciseTypes.Add(timedExercise);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: Just to clarify, by extending Cardio : BaseType...did you mean to extend Cardio : ExerciseBaseType?

Comment: @Reza yes! sorry for the typo, fixed!

Comment: Need a further point of clarification because I got stuck trying to model it the way you have it. Each Exercise will have one of four Exercise Types, however the data associated with the Exercise Type is per each exercise. Meaning if I have 10 exercises, each exercise can be of one 5 types, but the associated measure (time, weight, etc) would be for each exercise. As such, I don't think the model above works

Comment: @Reza I am not sure what you meant, I added further details, can you please check?